# Get value of cell on click and store as variable in worksheet_selectionChange sub and then pass variable to worksheet_Change sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store a cell value as a variable when the user clicks on the cell as part of a function for a worksheet_selectionChange  event. Like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing Then

    Dim intX As Integer
       intX = Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    End If

    End Sub
```

I then want to be able to retrieve this variable in my worksheet change event and display it in a message box when the user changes a value in my dropdown box.

Please can someone show me how I would do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing And Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "Please Select..." And Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "View Log" Then


MsgBox intX 

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Outside of your sub declare `intX` as this: `Public intX as Integer` see [Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx) for more information

Comment: @DragonSamu thanks for this suggestion however when I try this it gives me the number 0 in my message box instead of the cell value which should be 'test'

Comment: That is logical as its an Integer.  If you want a String declare your variable as a String

Comment: @DragonSamu ok thanks I tried labelling it as a string instead and now it is blank

Comment: What is your specific reason to use `Intersect`? Your issue is (besides the `String` problem) that in your `SelectionChange event` `Target` will `Match` if the `ActiveCell` is in `Column M`. But your `Change event` will never `Match` because the `Target` is always the `Cell` you were in.

Comment: Was the below answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to pass a `String` but declared it as an `Integer`.

And in your `SelectionChange event` `Target` will `Match` if the `ActiveCell` is in `Column M`. But your `Change event` will never `Match` because the `Target` is always the `Cell` you were in.

To solve this you need to check wether the `Target` is within the `Range("M:M")`

see code below:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M:M")) Is Nothing And _
Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "Please Select..." And _
Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "View Log" Then
```